# Where is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(y)}{\sqrt{(y - x_{1})^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}}\, dy$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth compactly supported function in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the function $$g(x_{1}, x_{2}) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(y)}{\sqrt{(y - x_{1})^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}}\, dy$$ where $x_{2} > 0$. Is then $g$ continuous in $\{(x_{1}, x_{2}): x_{2} > 0\}$?

Comment: What exactly is your problem in solving this?

Comment: I've been trying to base the proof of the proof that $(1/|x|) \ast f$ is continuous, however, the issue is that now the $1/\sqrt{(y - x_{1})^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}$ part is not a convolution so I can't easily do a change of variables to put the translation onto $f$. I was wondering what else I could try to do.

Comment: Some observations: First you can shift the integration limits $y\to y+x_1$ to get ridd of $x_1$ in the denominator. Then you can try to work directly with the definition of continuity. 
If $g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) h(x,y)\,{\rm d}y$ then $|g(x)-g(z)| = \left|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)[h(x,y)-h(z,y)]\,{\rm d}y\right| \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(y)||h(x,y)-h(z,y)|\,{\rm d}y \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(y)|\,{\rm d}y \times \max_y |h(x,y)-h(z,y)|$. The first term is finite since $f$ has compact support and you can use the Mean Value Theorem to bound the second term.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! After you're initial comment, I had an idea, I was wondering if it works? We have that the integral is equal to $g(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{f(y)1_{y_{2} = 0}}{|x - y|}\, dy$. Then to prove continuity of this, it is enough to show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(y)|1_{y_{2} = 0}\left|\frac{1}{|x_{0} - y|} - \frac{1}{|x - y|}\right|\, dy$ is small, but this is bounded above by $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(y)|\left|\frac{1}{|x_{0} - y|} - \frac{1}{|x - y|}\right|\, dy$ and now we proceed as in the proof of showing $(1/|x|) \ast f$ is continuous.

Comment: Can't I have a convergent integral even if the function diverges? For example, if I'm intergrating over a ball of radius R in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, $\int_{|x| \leq R}\frac{1}{|x|}\, dx = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}\frac{1}{r}r\, dr\, d\theta = 2\pi R$?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about 1D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b\ge 0,$ let $H_b= \{(x_1,x_2): x_2 > b\}.$ For any $(x_1,x_2) \in H_b, b>0,$ the integrand is in absolute value bounded above by

$$\frac{|f(y)|}{b} \in L^1(\mathbb {R}).$$

The dominated convergence theorem then shows that $g$ is continuous at each point of $H_b$ if $b>0.$ Since any point in $H_0$ lies in some $H_b,b>0,$ we have $g$ continuous on $H_0$ as desired.